# how to Traversal a list when this list contained a father list ,it use std list

Tags: c++, list

ALL, I use under code to traversal a std::list,but it only first node value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A{

public:

       int a;

       ...

       A();

       ~A();

       A(const A& t);

       A& operator =(const A& t);

};

class B{

public:

        ...

       list<A> lstA;

       B();

       ~B();

       B(const B& t);

       B& operator=(const B& t);

}

list<B> lstB;

int main(){


      B b;

      int i_test=0;

      while( i_test <5){


           A a;

           a.a = i_test ++;

           b.lstA.pushback(a);

      }
```

///this forgot to do
          lstB.pushback(b);

```
      list<B>::iterator itB = lstB.begin();
      for (; itB != lstB.end(); itB++){

            B b = *itB;
            list<A>::iterator itA = b.lstA.begin();
            for (; itA!= b.lstA.end(); itA++){

                  A a = *itA;
                  printf(" a value %d \n",a.a);
             }
        }


}
```

this code print so:
 a value 0

can not get other value

here is my real run code:

```
     list<Callout_Task>::iterator itTask = lstCalloutTasks.begin();
    /*pthread_mutex_lock(&taskMutex); */
    printf("%s,%d  has get the call out tasks size:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,lstCalloutTasks.size());
    for (;itTask != lstCalloutTasks.end(); itTask++)
    {
        Callout_Task nwayct = *itTask;
        //list<Callout_info> mylist(nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.begin(),nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.end());
        list<Callout_info>::iterator itInfo = nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.begin() ;
        printf("%s,%d  has get the call out info size:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.size());

        //for(; itInfo != nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.end(); itInfo++)
        //{
        while(itInfo != nwayct.lstCalloutInfo.end())
        {
            Callout_info nwayci = *itInfo;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&calloutMutex); 
            printf("%s,%d this call out number:%s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,nwayci.number.c_str());
            char szCmd[1024] = {0};
            itInfo ++;
         }
    }
```

it is only display first value of nwayct.lstCalloutInfo

Comment: You should probably explain what you expect is going to happen iterating `lstB`, since you never push anything in it. The posted code leaves `lstB` empty, so i expect nothing printed *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration is correct.
I would suggest you write

```
B& b = *itB;
```

instead of

```
B b = *itB;
```

(and same for A a = *itA;) to avoid copying the whole list each time.

As WhozCraig noticed, you just didn't push anything in lstB. That's why nothing shows up in the console.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
   int a;
};

class B
{
public:
   list<A> lstA;
};

list<B> lstB;

int main(){
  B b;
  int i_test=0;
  while( i_test <5){
       A a;
       a.a = i_test ++;
       b.lstA.push_back(a);
  }
  lstB.push_back(b);

  list<B>::iterator itB = lstB.begin();
  for (; itB != lstB.end(); itB++){
        B& b = *itB;
        list<A>::iterator itA = b.lstA.begin();
        for (; itA!= b.lstA.end(); itA++){

              A& a = *itA;
              printf(" a value %d \n",a.a);
         }
    }
}
```